# Jam Rolly-polly

Tags: cake

Today I made for the first time a jam rolly-polly. It is very tasty (if I do say so myself) and perfectly edible, however while it was cooking, the top layer split and did not rise.

Can anyone suggest what I did wrong - how do I ensure that it does not fall part slightly when I am cooking and rise so that it is similar to the pictures you see and the texture that I have eaten before.

Many thanks

Fiona

Comment: when you ask recipe fixing questions, it is best if you provide the recipe in your question, as well as any deviations from it that you made.

Answer (score 1):

Try baking it in a loaf pan instead of flat on a sheet. You can put a U shaped sheet of parchment under it to lift it out with. The side of the pan will give some resistance to it spreading out, which will hopefully keep the top from splitting. I've also seen folks crush up aluminum foil to pack the sides of the pan with to try to force it into a more rounded bottom.

Another trick I've heard, but not sure how well it works in practice, is to chill the rolled up product before you bake it, so that the dough won't "slouch" on the pan like a D shape on it's back, but will stay more round.

Comment: Most rolled items I've seen wouldn't fit in a regular loaf pan (too long), but it's possible that a  ["french bread pan"](http://www.amazon.com/Baguette-French-Perforated-Non-Stick-Aluminum/dp/B0015QPYQ8) might work.